# My parents' house number is 1702. My wife's mother's house in a different state is 1704.Thus they would be next door neighbors. What are the chances?

Tags: probability

My parents' house number is 1702. My wife's mother's house in a different state is 1704.  If they happened to live on the same street they would be next door neighbors. What are the chances of that?

Comment: Would 1703 be equally surprising? Or 2071?  What about your wife's father or brother or sister? Have either parents moved? Had you married before the most recent move? [John Edensor Littlewood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%27s_law) estimated that 1-in-a-million coincidences occur for any individual about once a month.

Comment: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3207/919.

Comment: So, in other words you don't know the answer.  Thanks for playing, Henry.